# How to set a dynamically loaded drop down list with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm looking for a way to select a dropdown value after it's dynamically loaded (with json values).
I want to do it after the load is completed.

Here is the example:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"/echo/json/",
    data:data,
    type:"POST",
    success:function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
       var items = '<option value="0">-- All --</option>';
     $.each(response, function (i, channel) {
         items += "<option value='" + channel.Value + "'>" + channel.Text + "</option>";
     });       

     $('#PromotionFilter_Channel_ID').html(items);
        // HERE IT WORKS :$("#PromotionFilter_Channel_ID").val(3);
    }
});

//test doesn't work
$("#PromotionFilter_Channel_ID").val(3);
```

Fiddle sample: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mrflo/UdaNA/2/

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Set your value in the success function after the `.each` loop. The reason you can't set it now is because AJAX is **asynchronous** and is still loading by the time that piece of code is hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull, ajax is async! This means the ajaxcall can still be busy while you try to select the options. You want this in the oncomplete of the ajaxcall.
This could occur if the requested page is slow or the connection is not optimal.

While the ajaxrequest is still doing its job, the rest of the javascript continues. You are trying to select an option that does not exist yet! Remember, you are thinking in miliseconds here.

You are actually giving the answer yourself, you want it 'when the ajax is completete`.

```
$("#PromotionFilter_Channel_ID").find('option[value="3"]'); // or more native:
```

Or

```
$("#PromotionFilter_Channel_ID")[0].selectedIndex = 3; // or 2, not sure if 0 based-index
```

Comment: I seem to have killed a suggested update, sorry about that. I'm not really used to someone changing my replies. I'll try to make it a bit more like the suggestion again

Answer (score 3):

When your ajax call is triggred, your code continue the execution flow since ajax calls are async by default. When you try to set the selected value, the combo box wasn't populated yet.

Although an ajax call could be executed in synchronous mode, normally it isn't the correct approach. You should assign selected value on success callback.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can try this

```
complete:function(){    
        $("#PromotionFilter_Channel_ID").val(3);
    }
```

Have modified the fiddle

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UdaNA/4/)